# how to make a synchronous android application with sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

Unfortunately, I didn't find a better title for the question 
i want to make application like a simple hotel reservation and i will make the database online if i add client to the hotel database via android application  i want it pending and  When I'm online i want the command execute but in the same time when i'm offline i want to see the that the command pending , it's like whatsapp when you send message while you are offline the message not send and you see it pending and when the internet available The message is sent automatically

so how i can do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite may well not be ideal solution. The reason being that SQLite is an embedded database not really designed for the client server model (the hotel database would, according to your decsription, be on a server). [Appropriate Uses For SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html)

Perhaps [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/)
 could be more appropriate.

However, if you wanted to use SQLite to just handle the requests from the device SQLite could perhaps be used for that aspect. For the requests to be sent automatically you'd need to look at perhaps running a service. [Services overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services). You would probably want to incorporate [Notifications](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications)

If using SQLite then the first step, database wise would be to design the database, the table(s) and the columns within the tables. However, to do so requires that the system itself is designed. System design, would depend upon what can actually be done.

Comment: Thank you but this is a required task in database course , so Is all I need in my task i Services and Notification in android ?!